# how is deletion of the entry in secondary table done

Tags: berkeley-db

let's assume we have a primary table, with following content:

```
key  value
--------------
a    andreas
b    bernd
c    chris
e    ernst
f    frank
g    gerold
```

and we created a seconardy, with a callback that just counts the letters in the primary data, we'll get

```
5 b
5 c
5 e
5 f
6 g
7 a
```

now, when I delete the entry for "ernst", the secondary entry "5 e" will be deleted too. How is determined, **which** secondary entry must be deleted? Does BDB execute the callback again, followed by a table-scan on the calculated value? "5" can be jumped on, but to find "5 e" there would be a cursor needed, right?

Answer (score 0):

The association between secondary <-> primary in Berkeley DB is on a unique identifier. So with key->value stores, the secondary value == the primary key.

With a unique identifier that associates the secondary <-> primary databases, there is no ambiguity.

Comment: the question is not about ambiguity, Since (as you said correctly) sec.data == pri.key, you can access the primary fully indexed. But accessing the secondary cannot be fully indexed, since the secondary key isn't unique. So deleting from it MUST do a cursor search? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not sure what you ask: cursors are used both internally and externally in BDB. The callback is called once with the primary key->value, and is responsible for creating the set of secondary key->value pairs for the operation (including deletion) associated with the unique primary key. No cursor is exposed to the callback. Why does it matter if an internal cursor is used (or not)?

Comment: I want to avoid a performance issue: when I delete the primary, I don't want BDB to do a table scan to delete the secondary, too. see my example: how does it know WHICH row of those with key "5" is to be deleted, without reading them all ?  (in my example there's only 4 of them,my life there wil have 10m+). Or is "e ernst" in primary and "5 e" in secondary connected somehow interally (invisible for me)?

Comment: Measurement is best performance tuning. Meanwhile, the doc claims more (rather than less) efficiency for secondary associated databases. Join operations (like this) are already highly optimized: its not like this is a sequential linear search. But try-and-see (and tune: there's surely tuning of cache/pagesize that helps).

Comment: You could probably achieve more performance by using a different secondary key than simply strlen. Have you considered adding the first few characters to the count? That SHOULD reduce your 10M+ key potential search space with little additional cost. Or just use a proper hash: the bias is likely towards short strings, a hash will be a uniform distribution.

Comment: yes, good point. Not using just the length, but also the whole string sounds promising ( the primary's data's length is limited). Using a not-fully-qualified key "5*" on the secondary will then to the same as using "5" did before, and deletion could be a lot faster. I think you're right, mass-testing will be the best advisor. I'll give it a try - it wouldn't be the first time BDB will surprise me pleasantly ;-)